# Do we need [getattribute]? What is it about?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've found [a number of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getattribute) tagged with [getattribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getattribute).

What is it about? Do we need it?

Comment: Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow. Before burnination can proceed your question needs a bit more info on how the tag meets the burnination criteria. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for clarifying. I will remove the `burninate-request` tag and provide more details.

Comment: It looks like it's used as a generic method name. Two options I see: 1) find out the language that most often uses that tag and affiliate it with that particular language's method, removing the tag from all other questions. 2) burninate the tag as it does not clarify anything. We can't exactly add a tag wiki since the tag is consistently used ambiguously, and both of my suggestions would involve a very long process indeed...

Comment: Just glancing at the questions. It seems they're all related to retrieving an HTML element's attribute.

Comment: @RubberDuck Yes, most of them seem to be related to retrieving an HTML element's attribute. However, there are a few questions related to getting attributes from a HTTP session.

Comment: Just found some questions tagged with [tag:setattribute].